# Month-date filter of the data frame?

Tags: r, date, datetime, filter

I currently have baseball data and hoping to filter a data frame to the games a player has played in during the week prior and after his birthday.  Having trouble filtering just by the month and day.

Code:

```
#create variable that is the month-day of the start of the 2017 season
start_2017 = format(as.Date(seasons_g_2017[seasons_g_2017$name == 2017,]$starts_on), "%m%d")

#create variable that is the month-day of the end of the 2017 season
end_2017 = format(as.Date(seasons_g_2017[seasons_g_2017$name == 2017,]$ends_on), "%m%d")

#create column in players_data that shows month-day of the player's birthday
players_data$birth_date_filter = as.Date(players_data$birth_date,"%m%d")

#filter players_data to only players who have a birthday during the actual season
players_data = players_data[players_data$birth_date_filter >= start_2017 & 
players_data$birth_date_filter <= end_2017,]
```

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: `lubridate` is a handy r tool for date/time work. I can't help much more without sample data.

Comment: @BH57, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functionality of `lubridate` package to handle the date time objects. For your data you just need to add `2017` to your datatime strings then convert it to datatime objects. After it you will be easily make comparisons and filtering:

library(lubridate)

```
# simulation
seasons_g_2017 = data.frame(name = 2017, 
                            starts_on = "April 2",
                            ends_on = "November 1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

players_data = data.frame(name = c("John", "Bill"), birth_date = c("January 15", "June 15"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# OP's data
# create variable that is the month-day of the start of the 2017 season
start_2017 <- ymd(paste0(2017, seasons_g_2017[seasons_g_2017$name == 2017, ]$starts_on, sep = " "))

# create variable that is the month-day of the end of the 2017 season
end_2017 <- ymd(paste0(2017, seasons_g_2017[seasons_g_2017$name == 2017, ]$ends_on, sep = " "))

# create column in players_data that shows month-day of the player's birthday
players_data$birth_date_filter <- ymd(paste0(2017, players_data$birth_date, sep = " "))

# filter players_data to only players who have a birthday during the actual season
players_data <- players_data[players_data$birth_date_filter >= start_2017 & 
                              players_data$birth_date_filter <= end_2017,]
players_data
```

Output:

```
  name birth_date birth_date_filter
2 Bill    June 15        2017-06-15
```